# OpenCV Kalman Filter Initialization Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to track 30 points in an image and want to stabilize the tracking using the Kalman Filter in the OpenCV library. I did this before for a single point and succeeded using the position and velocity of the point as states. Then, for 30 points I just decided to create 30 Kalman Filters, one for each point and put them in an array. However, I got an assertion error.

Is this the right/best way to track those 30 points in the image? Are there better ways to do this?

My code is below. The problem occurs in the StatePre line.

```
vector<KalmanFilter> ijvEdgeKF(30);

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    Point temp = calcEndPoint(ijv,170,i*360/30); //Calculates initial point
    ijvEdgeKF[i].statePre.at<float>(0) = temp.x; //State x
    ijvEdgeKF[i].statePre.at<float>(1) = temp.y; //State y
    ijvEdgeKF[i].statePre.at<float>(2) = 0; //State Vx
    ijvEdgeKF[i].statePre.at<float>(3) = 0; //State Vy

    ijvEdgeKF[i].transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(4, 4) << 1,0,0,0,   0,1,0,0,  0,0,1,0,  0,0,0,1);
    setIdentity(ijvEdgeKF[i].measurementMatrix);
    setIdentity(ijvEdgeKF[i].processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-4));
    setIdentity(ijvEdgeKF[i].measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-1));
    setIdentity(ijvEdgeKF[i].errorCovPost, Scalar::all(.1));
}
```

Solved. Problem was in the KalmanFilter initialization. I did not initialize the filter in the arrays so here is the solution:

```
vector<KalmanFilter> ijvEdgeKF;
ijvEdgeKF.clear();

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    Point temp = calcEndPoint(ijv,170,i*360/30); //Calculates initial point
    KalmanFilter tempKF(4,2,0);
    tempKF.statePre.at<float>(0) = temp.x; //State x
    tempKF.statePre.at<float>(1) = temp.y; //State y
    tempKF.statePre.at<float>(2) = 0; //State Vx
    tempKF.statePre.at<float>(3) = 0; //State Vy

    tempKF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(4, 4) << 1,0,0,0,   0,1,0,0,  0,0,1,0,  0,0,0,1);
    setIdentity(tempKF.measurementMatrix);
    setIdentity(tempKF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-4));
    setIdentity(tempKF.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-1));
    setIdentity(tempKF.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(.1));
    ijvEdgeKF.push_back(tempKF);
}
```

Still have one question though, is this the only way to track the multiple points in an image or is there a better way?

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)(size.p[0]*size.p[1]) && elemSize() == (((((DataType<_Tp>::type) & ((512 - 1) << 3)) >> 3) + 1) << ((((sizeof(size_t)/4+1)*16384|0x3a50) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::type)
 & ((1 << 3) - 1))*2) & 3))) in unknown function, file c:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 569

Comment: @mohikhsan: I am working on a similar problem. I am also tracking multiple objects. Can you share with me the further code, on how did you work on measurement and prediction ? That would be grateful if you can share that particular code ? I am quite confused with Kalman Filter. That's why I ask. My email id is thisiskarthic@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not initializing your KalmanFilters correctly, thus the  statePre Mat is empty.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    ijvEdgeKF[i].init(4,4);  // int dynamParams, int measureParams
    ijvEdgeKF[i].statePre.at<float>(0) = 3; //State x
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, just figured it out myself as well a few minutes ago.