# Kalman filter inside a struct and cannot initialize it

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

I want to track multiple objects using Kalman Filter. So, what I am doing is, I am using a struct to define the object's properties and also a Kalman Filter to track its points. (As follows)

```
struct sAsparagus
    {
        int iId;
        int iFrameId;
        int iWidth;
        int iHeight;
        int iX;
        int iY;
        int iZ;
        cv::KalmanFilter KF; // Here I am defining the Kalman filter and cannot initialize.
    };
```

Then in a for loop, I am trying to assign some values to these properties.

```
   for (CvBlobs::const_iterator it = blobs.begin(); it !=blobs.end();++it)
    {
        sAsparagus sAsp;
        sAsp.iFrameId = iCounter;

        sAsp.iWidth = (it->second->maxx - it->second->minx);
        sAsp.iHeight = (it->second->maxy - it->second->miny);
        sAsp.iX = it->second->centroid.x;
        sAsp.iY = it->second->centroid.y;
        sAsp.KF(4, 2, 0);   //Here I am getting an error
        vAspElements.push_back(sAsp);
    }
```

When I run, I get an error as follows.

```
  no match for call to ‘(cv::KalmanFilter) (int, int, int)’
sAsp.KF(4, 2, 0);
```

How can I initialize my Kalman filter here ? Is this approach right ? I also came to see here ([OpenCV Kalman Filter Initialization Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739340/opencv-kalman-filter-initialization-error)) some approach for multiple objects tracking using Kalman filter. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried by copy assignment? `sAsp.KF = cv::KalmanFilter(4, 2, 0);`

Comment: @JamesAdkison Yes, it is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sAsp.KF(4, 2, 0);` cannot be used as `KF` was default constructed when you do `sAsparagus sAsp;`.  You cannot call the constructor on an already constructed object.  You can assign to `KF` with a temporary `KalmanFilter` though like:

```
sAsp.KF = cv::KalmanFilter(4, 2, 0);
```

Or you could use `init()` like

```
sAsp.KF.init(4, 2, 0);
```